# Xamarin forms MVVM Stacklayout children binding

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I want to binding data(children) from my ViewModel to StackLayout.


In XAML I want something like:

```
<StackLayout Content="{Binding MainStackLayout}"/>
```

Is there anyway how to make this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? And what errors or problems are you currently experiencing?

Comment: Yes, you simply need to have your ViewModel have a property of `public View MainStackLayout { get; set; }` (with property changed method in the setter).

Comment: If you put controls (your stacklayout content) in the viewmodel it really breaks the MVVM pattern.  You are suppose to separate the view from the viewmodel.

Comment: So should I keep stacklayout in view?

Comment: I'm not sure if you already did it, but I strongly recommend you to read the [xamarin developers site article about MVVM](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/mvvm/). When you break a pattern, as @KenTucker advised you, you'll have to struggle with even bigger problems in the future, it doesn't worth..

Comment: I will read it, thank you for your advice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin forms MVVM Stacklayout content binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41322399/xamarin-forms-mvvm-stacklayout-content-binding)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a StackLayout has no "Content" property. Now if you want to bind some content inside that would be in form of

```
<StackLayout Children="{Binding MyChildren}"/>
```

Your whatever BindingContext (your model) must implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and the variable can look like:

```
private List<View> _MyChildren;
public List<View> MyChildren
{
    get { return _MyChildren; }
    set
    {
        if (_MyChildren != value)
        {
            _MyChildren = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Children is not bindable you need to do something like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41323262/33