# Binded ViewModel content to Stacklayout

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, viewmodel

I am trying to bind content from my viewmodel to my view.

I am using a code snippet that creates a custom StackLayout where we can bind items to it.

However I am not making this work and i see no update on my UI. I am unsure what exactly to bind to the "Items". I am currently binding an observablecollection with buttons but it does not show.

This is the custom stacklayout:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;

class CustomStackLayout : StackLayout
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Items), typeof(ObservableCollection<View>), typeof(CustomStackLayout), null,
            propertyChanged: (b, o, n) =>
            {
                (n as ObservableCollection<View>).CollectionChanged += (coll, arg) =>
                {
                    switch (arg.Action)
                    {
                        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                            foreach (var v in arg.NewItems)
                                (b as CustomStackLayout).Children.Add((View)v);
                            break;
                        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                            foreach (var v in arg.NewItems)
                                (b as CustomStackLayout).Children.Remove((View)v);
                            break;
                        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
                            //Do your stuff
                            break;
                        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
                            //Do your stuff
                            break;
                    }
                };
            });


    public ObservableCollection<View> Items
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<View>)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

And this is how i gather my content.

```
    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
       CategoryName = new ObservableCollection<Button>();
    }

    ObservableCollection<Button> _categoryName;
    public ObservableCollection<Button> CategoryName
    {
        get
        {
            return this._categoryName;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_categoryName != value)
            {
                this._categoryName = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("CategoryName");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
```

Then i gather new data in a void:

```
private async void LoadCategories()
    {

        var GetCategories = await Data.Categories();
        CategoryName = new ObservableCollection<Button>();

        foreach (var Category in GetCategories["results"])
        {
            var CategoryButton = new Button();
            CategoryButton.Text = Category["CategoryName"].ToString().ToUpper();
            CategoryName.Add(CategoryButton);
        }
    }
```

The xaml:

```
     <ContentPage x:Name="ParentView">

     <ScrollView x:Name = "CategoriesScrollView">
          <controls:CustomStackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="20" Items = "{Binding BindingContext.CategoryName, Source={x:Reference ParentView}}" />
     </ScrollView>
```

View:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = new MainPageViewModel();
}
```

Comment: Can you show us code where you are declaring CategoryName collection. Please edit your question and include that part also.

Comment: @AlmirVuk Added `BindingContext = new MainPageViewModel();` and `CategoryName = new ObservableCollection<Button>();` in the viewmodel constructor

Comment: when do you load the data?

Comment: Inside `LoadCategories ();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things,

This class should be public....

```
class BindableStackLayout : StackLayout
{..
```

to

```
public class BindableStackLayout : StackLayout
{..
```

And

```
 <ScrollView x:Name = "CategoriesScrollView">
      <controls:CustomStackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="20" Items = "{Binding BindingContext.CategoryName, Source={x:Reference ParentView}}" />
 </ScrollView>
```

to

```
 <ScrollView x:Name = "CategoriesScrollView">
      <controls:BindableStackLayout  Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="20" Items = "{Binding CategoryName}" />
 </ScrollView>
```

You defined your class as BindableStacklayout and you are referencing CustomStackLayout on Xaml.

You dont need to add x:refe since the bindingcontext of the page is set to the viewModel you want.

Hope this fixes it?

Comment: Ah sorry. I have it as "CustomStackLayout" instead of "BindableStackLayout" in my real code. 

Secondly i changed it to public but still no change hmm..

This is the code sample i use btw and apparently people made it work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41322399/xamarin-forms-mvvm-stacklayout-content-binding

Comment: @CarlosRodrigez to me this is not a good idea. From my opinion, viewmodel should only have data, no ui components. So bindablestacklayout should have IEnumerable<string> which is list of your category name. On property changed or collection changed, if you want dynamic view, you should be using datatemplateselector for that

Comment: Could u show me an exmaple of what u mean? I am not following 100 %.

Comment: @CarlosRodrigez can you tell me what is the use case of this code? And i will make an example what you want to achieve. I want to understand why bindable stacklayout should have dynamic view contents

Comment: I am creating a scrollable horizontal category list based on the data i have in my database.

Comment: @CarlosRodrigez does it always need to be button? those it need to be dynamic ?

Comment: Yes it has to be a button. Or well, it can be a a label too with a gesturerecognizar attached to it. But it has to be clickable

Comment: I filter data based on what button the user press. I also do basic UIview updating. So if u click on one button then that one will be fontattributes = "bold" and the rest "none"

Comment: @CarlosRodrigez Why not use listview? set up a datatemplate and set tapesture on the view?

Comment: Listview is not horizontal

Comment: @CarlosRodrigez One sec i will create a sample app

Comment: @CarlosRodrigez just curious 'LoadCategories ();' where did you call this method? i dont see it you calling this method

Comment: @CarlosRodrigez [Example app](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1h1MGKmDDo4m3_lFJF8Ppd_u1fOiDtSdA)

Comment: I will check it now! :)

Comment: Ur sample works but not my app when i use data logic. Will look into it in a few hours to see why it does not work for me. Thanks a lot for the work u put in. Marking ur answer as complete.